# Remove directory, move subtree up one level

Tags: windows-7

Hi I recently installed windows 7 on another PC and copied my music across, unfortunately I accidentally copied the root music folder so my new (windows 7) folder structure is E:\me\Music\music\ (all files and folders of my music). While I could no doubt simply copy and paste the files and folders to achieve my desired structure of E:\me\Music\music\ (all files and folders of my music) I wondered if there was a better way that would avoid the timely process of reading and writing the hard drive.
Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just rename `E:\Me\Music` to something different then copy the `E:\Me\Music\music` subfolder out to the `E:\Me` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copy and paste, use cut and paste (Ctrl-X instead of Ctrl-C). This will do a move instead of a copy, and should complete instantly.